# Angular 7: Data displays on page, but console has Cannot read property

Tags: angular, promise, observable, angular7

I am working with an Angular 7 app that I am building, and I am having some issue with returning data from my API, and writing it on the page properly.

I have tried to follow guides around promises and observables, but I have not seem to been able to either get the data to display in the header properly, or in this case get the console to stop throwing errors. I have tried using the [Elvis](https://www.joshmorony.com/safely-displaying-data-with-the-elvis-operator/) operator, but that just makes the display value blank instead of displaying the value.

resume.service.ts

```
export class ResumeService {
  nameURL: string = 'REDACTED';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getName() {
    return this.http.get(this.nameURL);
  }
}
```

Return of this.http.get(this.nameURL);

```
[
  {
    name: 'My Name'
  }
]
```

navbar.component.ts

```
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  data: Name;
  reason = '';
  @ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav: MatSidenav;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private resumeAPI: ResumeService) {
    this.resumeAPI.getName().subscribe(res => {
      this.data = res[0];
    });
  }

  close(reason: string) {
    this.reason = reason;
    this.sidenav.close();
  }
}

export interface Name {
  name: string
}
```

navbar.component.html

```
<div>
  <a routerLink="/">
    {{ this.data.name }}
  </a>
</div>
```

So, in the navbar I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNsFe.png) (it shows my name where the blurred out area is - which is the data the API returns)

But, in the console I see the following [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvlfR.png)
(The link has the picture of the console errors, but this is the specifics:
Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

I understand that it is throwing the error before the API provides the data for the render, but I am not sure how to get around it since changing the HTML to {{ this.data?.name }} makes the navbar become blank, and {{ this.data.name? }} causes this error: Unexpected end of expression:  {{ this.data.name? }}

Comment: Just use `{{ this.data?.name }}`, data is undefined until your api call succeeds, hence the console error. The template will display the name once `data` is defined. Read about "safeNavigation" operator

Comment: I already went through that, the `{{ this.data?.name }}` leaves the field blank indefinitely and never renders the new data..

Comment: May try using `{{ this.data?.name }}` and call ChangeDetection in your API-call

Comment: @MullisS that did the trick!

Comment: @MullisS I posted the solution and gave you credit! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for this issue was to use the Angular core ChangeDetectorRef with detectChanges(). All credit goes to **@MullisS**

In the TypeScript file we changed:
`import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';` to `import { Component, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';` (added the ChangeDetectorRef).

In the constructor, we changed:
`constructor(private resumeAPI: ResumeService) {` to `constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef, private resumeAPI: ResumeService) {`

And, in the subscribe function, we changed:

```
this.resumeAPI.getName().subscribe(res => {
  this.data = res[0];
});
```

to

```
this.resumeAPI.getName().subscribe(res => {
  this.data = res[0];
  this.ref.detectChanges();
});
```

---

Below is the complete code solution for reference:
navbar.component.html

```
<a routerLink="/" >
  {{ this.data?.name }}
</a>
```

navbar.component.html

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
import { MatSidenav } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ResumeService } from '../services/resume.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss'],
  providers: [ResumeService]
})
export class NavbarComponent {
  data: Name;
  reason = '';
  @ViewChild('sidenav') sidenav: MatSidenav;

  constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef, private resumeAPI: ResumeService) {
    this.resumeAPI.getName().subscribe(res => {
      this.data = res[0];
      this.ref.detectChanges();
    });
  }

  close(reason: string) {
    this.reason = reason;
    this.sidenav.close();
  }
}

export interface Name {
  name: string
}
```

Answer (score 2):

remove "this" in the HTML file

```
{{ data.name }}
```

Comment: Yes, the data does come over properly but does not render on the page once the view has the data.. I think you may have misunderstood my issue. Thank you though.

Comment: remove this in the html file: {{data.name}}

Comment: So yes that is correct, but the error still occurs. Using this.ref.detectChanges(); after assigning this.data to res[0] works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `this.http.get()` performs an async operation. So before running the `this.data = res[0];` line, `this.data`is not initialized yet and it throws an error.

You just need to check if `this.data` is set via

```
<a routerLink="/" *ngIf="this.data">
    {{ this.data.name }}
</a>
```

Or

```
<a routerLink="/">
    {{ this.data?.name }}
</a>
```

But I think the first one make more sense since you might not want to show link until its text is set

---

**OR**

You can use `async` pipe to make Angular deal with subscription itself.

```
this.data = this.resumeAPI.getName().pipe(map(res => res[0]));
```

And in template

```
<a routerLink="/">
   {{ (this.data | async).name }}
</a>
```

Comment: So tried both.. the first does not work with the ngif, as it never shows the data.. it just stays blank.. Same with the this.data? as I said earlier..  -  as for the second half, I did exactly as you said and unfortunately i am getting the same error in the console. "Cannot read property 'name' of null"

Comment: Where do you place `console.log`?

Comment: No im sorry, I am not console.log'ing anything. When I implements the `this.data = this.resumeAPI.getName().pipe(map(res => res[0]));` in my constructor for the navbar, and `<a routerLink="/">{{ (this.data | async).name }}</a>` in my HTML, the error console spits out  "Cannot read property 'name' of null"

Comment: Using the `{{ this.data?.name }}' in conjunction with @MullisS answer of using this.ref.detectChanges(); after assigning this.data to res[0] works as expected.